# how can i get device id,name or serial number using adobe flex builder?

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, air, device

I need a Uniq Number or uniq ID on my Android device, but I can't find anything.

My application runs on an Android device, and I use Adobe Flex Builder, and I want to store a device id for a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the answers provided in this discussion on the Adobe Forums:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/803428

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look on the following:
http://mateuszmackowiak.wordpress.com/category/native-dialog/